# How can I compute a dragged div's position

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

http://jsfiddle.net/prince4prodigy/vR2DU/7/

How can I compute a dragged div's position?

if you re-size the window you can see 'left' & 'top' property of div but if you drag div, 'left' & 'top' property don't computing (real time)

HTML:

```
<div id="container" class="container-container-fluid">
     if you drag div, 'left' & 'top' property dont computing (real time)
     <div id="div1" class="item drag">div</div>
</div>

<div id="left"></div>
<div id="right"></div>
```

JS:

```
$(function(){

       $( ".drag" ).draggable({ 
         containment : '#container'

       }); 


       function wResize() {

         var winW = $(window).width();
         var Body = $('body');
         var d = $('#div1').position();


         $('#div1').css({
             position:'absolute',
             color:'red'}); 

        //show value of left & top property
         $('#left').html('left : ' + d.left )
         $('#right').html('top : ' + d.top)

 }

 wResize();

$(window).resize(function() {
    wResize();
});

});
```

EDIT: the jsfiddle edited, please see it again.

Comment: are you looking for the drag event? http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#event-drag

Comment: i only want compute position of dragged element.

Comment: Yes that event handler will give you the position and offset of the current dragged element while dragging

Answer (score 2):

There is a `drag` event within the `draggable()` method. This function will get called every time there is a 'drag':

```
$( ".drag" ).draggable({ 
    containment : '#container',
    tolerance: 'touch',
    drag:wResize
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vR2DU/11/)

Comment: i want when resize window left & top property are computing, please see jsfiddle again.  http://jsfiddle.net/prince4prodigy/vR2DU/7/

Comment: @NazaninGoodarzi ? but that doesn't add what this answer suggested

Comment: i remove top & left property from div when window is resizing.

Comment: I don't really understand what your issue is?

Comment: @F4r-20   
 
i want when resize window left & top property are computing, please see jsfiddle again. jsfiddle.net/prince4prodigy/vR2DU/7

Comment: And so they are (if the width is less than 600px, you're condition, not mine)

Comment: this condition does not matter, you can remove it.

Comment: OK.. Couldn't you have done that yourself? [JSFiddle updated](http://jsfiddle.net/vR2DU/11/)..

Comment: no, this is not my purpose... please see this link & fix it http://jsfiddle.net/prince4prodigy/vR2DU/7/

Comment: Or u can remove this code from jQuery code `top: '10%', left: '10%'`.

Comment: What is it about the fiddle you just provided that isn't working? The left is being updated on resize and drag. The top won't change on resize because the height of the container doesn't change.

Comment: ok, you can Disregard the top property. the left property is enough.

Comment: So your question is answered?

Comment: when you resize the window left property of div show  in `$('#test').html()`.

Comment: Was that supposed to be a question? What am I supposed to do with that?

Comment: An obvious question has a question mark at the end. So no, no you didn't.

Answer (score 2):

Why you dont use the drag event of the Draggable DIV

You can use this way

```
drag: function( event, ui ) {
var l=ui.position.left;
var t=ui.position.top;
}
```

Comment: i want when resize window left & top property are computing, please see jsfiddle again.  http://jsfiddle.net/prince4prodigy/vR2DU/7/

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it will bind a function to the drag event and execute the same code you defined in your function:

```
$(".drag").draggable({
        containment: '#container',
        tolerance: 'touch',        
            drag: function(){
                var winW = $(window).width();
                var Body = $('body');
                var d = $('#div1').position();
                $('#left').html('left : ' + d.left)
            $('#right').html('top : ' + d.top)
            }

    });
```

Here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rvaldez/6hugy/)

Comment: i want when resize window left & top property are computing.

Comment: They are, look at the fiddle for the full code, the div will update if you resize or drag : http://jsfiddle.net/rvaldez/6hugy/

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're after:

```
$(function () {

    $(".drag").draggable({
        containment: '#container',
        tolerance: 'touch',
        drag: wResize
    });

    $(window).resize(wResize);

});

function wResize() {

    var winW = $(window).width();
    var Body = $('body');
    var d = $('#div1').position();

    if (winW < '600') {

        $('#div1').css({
            top: '10%',
            left: '10%',
            position: 'absolute',
            color: 'red'
        });

        $('#left').html('left : ' + d.left)
        $('#right').html('top : ' + d.top)
    }
}
```

You have to initialize the draggable plugin with the resize function as the drag parameter.

I created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abduncan/Wx2Gv/)

Comment: i want when resize window left & top property are computing, please see jsfiddle again. jsfiddle.net/prince4prodigy/vR2DU/7

Comment: It already does that??  Perhaps I am not understanding clearly what you are looking for.  Keep in mind you have IF statement in there for window width.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one....[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zBDCh/3/)

```
           $(function(){    
             $( ".drag" ).draggable({ 
             containment : '#container',
             tolerance: 'touch',
               drag: function(e,u){                  
             $('#left').html('left : ' + u.position.left )
             $('#right').html('top : ' +u. position.top)                   

               }
           });
```

Comment: i want when resize window left & top property are computing, please see jsfiddle again.  http://jsfiddle.net/prince4prodigy/vR2DU/7/